# Criteria for mongoTemplate

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

```
BasicQuery query = new BasicQuery("{}");
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(FaceFields.isValid).is(true)
    .orOperator(
        Criteria.where(FaceFields.FIRSTNAME).regex(q),
        Criteria.where(FaceFields.LASTNAME).regex(q),
        Criteria.where(FaceFields.MIDDLENAME).regex(q)    
    )
);
```

This is query, which I want to use, to get users. It works correct if all fields exists in documents. Otherwise it throws `NullPointerException`. How I can change this query, to check if some fields not exists and should not regex by q.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$exists` operator of MongoDB.

Within Java it should be used like this:

```
Criteria.where("myField").exists(true)
```

MongoDB's `$and` operator uses short circuit evaluation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

*"If the first expression (e.g. expression1) evaluates to false, MongoDB will not evaluate the remaining expressions."*

Though it should be possible to do (pseudo code query):

```
WHERE (
    ( isValid = true )
  AND (
    ( EXISTS(firstname, true) AND REGEXP(firstname, q) )
    OR
    ( EXISTS(lastname, true) AND REGEXP(lastname, q) )
    OR
    ( EXISTS(middlename, true) AND REGEXP(middlename, q) )
  )
)
```